# How do you compile a UDF in Cloudera's distribution of Hadoop+Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, user-defined-functions, cloudera

I am running Cloudera's VM (CH3). I've copied a simple UDF in my text editor, but I don't know how to compile it in order to be able to call it in a script. The Pig UDF manual http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/udf.html says to build pig.jar, however the link to SVN is broken: svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/pig/trunk. Can somebody please walk me through how to they were able to compile a UDF? thank you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [Maven repository from Cloudera](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/Using+the+CDH3+Maven+Repository), you just specify Pig as a dependency in your project.
When you build your project it is good idea to use option [jar-with-dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven) then it is much easier to use this UDF in your scripts (no more problems with classpath)